How to solve functional derivative of the integral of a functional
This question is originated from another question.
I want to find the functional derivative with respect to $q(\cdot \mid x)$ of something similar to:
$$
L(q) = -\int p(x) \int q(z \mid x) \log q(z \mid x)\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dx + \int \mu(x) (\int q(z \mid x)\,\mathrm dz-1)\,\mathrm dx \tag{1}
$$
which should be the Lagrangian of maximizing the expected entropy of $q(z \mid x)$ subject to $q(z \mid x)$ being a probability density. $\mu(x)$ is the Lagrange multiplier. The probability density $p(x)$ is known. Since I never learned functional analysis, I'm viewing functionals & functional derivative, a youtube video, in order to solve this problem; and unfortunately I get stuck.
However, if I assume that $p(x) = \sum_{j=1}^m \pi_j \delta(x-x_j)$ is a mixture of Dirac delta densities, $L(q)$ reduces to:
$$
L(q) = -\sum_{j=1}^m \pi_j \int q(z \mid x_j) \log q(z \mid x_j)\,\mathrm dz + \sum_{j=1}^m \mu_j (\int q(z \mid x_j)\,\mathrm dz - 1)
$$
and I'm pretty sure that the functional derivative w.r.t. $q(z \mid x_j)$ should be:
$$
-\pi_j (1 + \log q(z \mid x_j)) + \mu_j
$$
Thus, I speculate that in the original problem (Equation (1)), the functional derivative w.r.t. $q(z \mid x)$ should be similarly:
$$
-p(x) (1 + \log q(z \mid x)) + \mu(x)
$$
Could anyone confirm this? Thank you so much!
